# How to check for or avoid ERR_TIMED_OUT error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm occasionally getting a ERR_TIMED_OUT when scraping a site and want to know how I can catch the error so I can start the loop processing it again?

This is the function I'm using the get the response:

```
const responsePending = page.waitForResponse((response) => {
    return response.url().includes('cloudfront.net');
});

console.log('Wait for response...');
var response = await responsePending;
// when there's an error it doesn't print the next line
console.log('Response received: '+response.status());
```

And this is the error I'm sometimes getting:

```
This site can’t be XXXXX took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall

ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

Puppeteer also records this error in the logs:

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

Comment: Use a `try/catch` on `await responsePending`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule nope, that doesn't work either. I wrapped it in a try / catch but it still throws the error and displays the ERR_TIMED_OUT page. It's odd.

Comment: That could be because waitForResponse executes synchronously. Make the callback  passed to `waitForResponse` async with the async keyword.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options

Set the `timeout` option to 0

```
const responsePending = page.waitForResponse((response) => {
    return response.url().includes('cloudfront.net');
},{timeout:0});
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't stop the error. I'm not sure if the problem is the initial request is made to site A which sends a download request to site B (cloudfront.net) where the content is stored. I just got the same error even if I include the timeout:0.